# getting RetrofitError When uploading a video file as multipart request

Tags: java, spring, retrofit

I want to upload a video in a multipart request using Retrofit.

The following method sends a POST request to */video/{id}/data*, it returns true if the request succeeds and the appropriate HTTP error status otherwise:

```
//..
@Controller
public class VideoController {
//....
    @Multipart
    @RequestMapping(value = "/video/{id}/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean setVideoData(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Part("data") TypedFile videoData, HttpServletResponse response) {
           try {
                // save the video data
                // use a VideoFileHelper to store the file...
                // VideoFileHelper.saveVideoData(videoData.in());
                //...
                response.setStatus(200);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response.setStatus(404);
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

When uploading video file using the following code,

```
File testVideoData = new File("src/test/resources/test.mp4");
TypedFile file = new TypedFile("video/mp4", testVideoData);
boolean result = setVideoData(1, file);
                 ^
```

I get this error:

> retrofit.RetrofitError: 500 Server Error
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [retrofit.mime.TypedFile]: No default
>   constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: `retrofit.mime.TypedFile.<init>()`

This error is independent from the implementation of *setVideoData(...)* and this is why I commited the instructions within try bloc.